# Synonymize/merge [prototype] into [prototyping]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

There are two very similar tags:

- [prototyping](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prototyping), currently 119 questions and a decent tag excerpt and wiki.
- [prototype](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prototype), currently 25 questions (5 of which also have the [prototyping](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prototyping) tag) without excerpt and wiki.

I think it would be good to synonymize/merge both tags.

Comment: I think they should be merged into [prototype] and the same goes for [wireframing] into [wireframe]...

Comment: This has been completed.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with this tag merge.

A user likely isn't going to spend any time to figure out the nuanced distinction between

- the actual item produced ([prototype](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prototype)) and
- the process of creating the item ([prototyping](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prototyping))

If someone said "I have a question about prototypes," and then proceeded to ask you about your process for creating them, you probably wouldn't look at them strange, because the process to create them is related to the topic of "prototypes".

Answer (score 0):

It's a good point, but I wonder if it is useful to still make the distinction between the two tags because there are probably questions relating specifically to the actual prototype developed compared (which fits the tag 'prototype') to the process of creating prototypes (which fits the tag 'prototyping').

This could also be the case with using the tag 'tests' to discuss different types of user testing as opposed to questions specifically relating to how to run a specific type of user test.

But I am interested in other people's thoughts on this.