# Several proposed tag synonym suggestions still pending

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

<s>[wireframing](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wireframing) → [wireframe](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wireframe) ([Meta discussion](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3366))</s> *(Completed)*
<s>[prototyping](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prototyping) → [prototype](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prototype) ([Meta discussion](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3364))</s> *(Completed)*
<s>[manditory-fields](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manditory-fields) → [required-fields](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/required-fields) ([Meta discussion](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3410))</s> *([manditory-fields](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manditory-fields) currently has no questions)*
<s>[engagement](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engagement) → [user-engagement](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-engagement) ([Meta discussion](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3386))</s> *(Completed)*

Are we waiting on anything before creating these synonyms? They've been suggested, discussed (most of them), and then forgotten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through the list, the first two were merged even though the tag usage was different between the source and target words. They've been proposed and there hasn't been any feedback so I don't think the changes will have much objections since the synonyms have been created.

I am waiting for some feedback for the third pair as it is a much more recent proposal (so I want to give it some time first) but the last pair have been merged as well because it didn't make much sense to have both tags since engagements in the UX content implies user engagement.